# Number of stationary points of a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, stationary-point

Consider a polynomial with degree n. Then the greatest number of stationary points it may have is n-1. How can we build intuition or prove for why this is the case?

However, my main question is as follows. Consider a polynomial of degree 4. It is possible for that polynomial to have 1 stationary point. Where do the other stationary points go? Could it be they overlap each other and count as a single stationary point?

Comment: Does it help to consider that the derivative of a polynomial of degree $n$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$? The roots of the derivative polynomial correspond to stationary points.

Comment: It depends on your meaning of number of stationary points, if you count multiplicity you always have $n-1$ stationary points (in an algebraicly closed field), but as for example $x^4$ only has one distinct root $x = 0$, with multiplicity four, it also has one stationary point $x = 0$, which is the one distinct root of its derivative $4x^3$, with multiplicity three.

Answer (score 0):

The [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) (FTA) states: every non-zero, single-variable, degree $n$ polynomial with complex coefficients has counted with multiplicity, exactly $n$ complex roots.

If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, it is clear by the power rule that its derivative $P'(x)$ will have degree $n-1$. Since the stationary points of $P(x)$ are defined to occur at the roots of $P'(x)$, FTA tells us that $P(x)$ will have at most $n-1$ stationary points.

As for your question, FTA only states that $P'(x)$ will have exactly $n-1$ *complex* roots. It may just so happen that some of those roots are real. Those real roots will correspond to stationary points while the remaining non-real ones correspond to the "missing" stationary points.